# Error in google cloud speech api synchronous speech recognition docs

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I copied the information from the google cloud speech api synchronous speech recognition docs at https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/sync-recognize into my code, but I when I ran the code I received a lot of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 121, in inner
    return to_call(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 68, in inner
    return a_func(*updated_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 487, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 437, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, sample_rate_hertz (16000) in RecognitionConfig must either be omitted or match the value in the WAV header ( 44100).)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TESTINGAUDIO.py", line 27, in <module>
    print (transcribe_file("output.wav"))
  File "TESTINGAUDIO.py", line 20, in transcribe_file
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/speech/v1/speech_client.py", line 201, in recognize
    return self._recognize(request, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 452, in inner
    return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 438, in base_caller
    return api_call(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 376, in inner
    return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 127, in inner
    ' classified as transient', exception)
google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, sample_rate_hertz (16000) in RecognitionConfig must either be omitted or match the value in the WAV header ( 44100).)>)
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import io
def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

print (transcribe_file("output.wav"))
```

Can someone please help me fix this error?

Here is the second batch of errors after taking sorak's suggestion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 121, in inner
    return to_call(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 68, in inner
    return a_func(*updated_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 487, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 437, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels.)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TESTINGAUDIO.py", line 26, in <module>
    print (transcribe_file("output.wav"))
  File "TESTINGAUDIO.py", line 20, in transcribe_file
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/speech/v1/speech_client.py", line 201, in recognize
    return self._recognize(request, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 452, in inner
    return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 438, in base_caller
    return api_call(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 376, in inner
    return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 127, in inner
    ' classified as transient', exception)
google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels.)>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message seems to be complaining about:

```
sample_rate_hertz=16000
```

because that is specifying a sample rate which is in conflict with the standard wav sample rate of 44100. It says that this value

```
must either be omitted or match the value in the WAV header
```

... so what happens if you just remove that line?

Comment: There are still a bunch of errors. It has to do with the type of file I think.

Comment: Yes, I posted them. I think cloud speech might only be able to transcribe audio that is encoded as LINEAR16 because that is the encoding specified in function.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554638/creating-suitable-wav-files-for-google-speech-api
And here: https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-asynchronous-speech-recognition-in-python-b1215d501c64
For a way to convert your file into a mono wav before passing it to Google

Comment: IT WORKS THANKS SO MUCH!!.

Comment: Excellent. Please accept my answer and upvote if you're feeling particularly thankful

Comment: You accept it by clicking the check mark. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ... upvoting requres 15 rep, so you can't yet

Comment: Ok I clicked the chec.

Comment: Thanks for the help.